# Object inspector extension in Jupyter Notebook?

Tags: python, ide

I am using Jupyter notebook to learn Python, and was looking for an object inspector extension for the notebooks which is there in Spyder labs ? I have installed various extensions like code-snippets, auto-completion, variable inspector, but I am not able to find this particular extension.